# How to remove double click editing for ListCell

Tags: java, listview, javafx, cell

I have a `ListView` with the languages one employee can speak. It uses custom `ListCells` implemented with the help of `setCellFactory`. I have a `ListCellFactory` class where I stored the `call` for my custom `ListCell`. In my `LanguageListCell` (my custom `ListCell` class) I have a `ContextMenu` in which I have a `MenuItem`. The `MenuItem` fires an event to edit the selected `ListCell`. The only problem I have encountered in my project is having this double click editing. Whenever I click more than once (when the `Cell` is not selected) or once (when the `Cell` is selected) the `startEdit` gets called. What I want to accomplish is remove this double click editing. But what I have managed to write as a code causes too many problems. For example, when I click on the `TextField` which is used for the editing, the `cancelEdit` method is called. And, basically, I can't even click on the `TextField` without removing it.

See my code for reference

This is the `LanguageListCell` class

```
package application;

import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

public class LanguageListCell extends ListCell<String> {
private TextField textField;
LanguageListCell cell = this;
int i = 0;


public LanguageListCell(ListView<String> languages) {

    ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

    cell.setEditable(true);


    MenuItem editItem = new MenuItem();
    editItem.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("Edit \"%s\"", cell.itemProperty()));

    editItem.setOnAction(event -> {
        languages.edit(cell.getIndex());
        //cell.startEdit();
    });

    contextMenu.getItems().add(editItem);

    cell.textProperty().bind(cell.itemProperty());

    cell.emptyProperty().addListener((obs, wasEmpty, isNowEmpty) -> {
        if (isNowEmpty) {
            cell.setContextMenu(null);
        } else {
            if (getString() != "Add") {
                cell.setContextMenu(contextMenu);

            }
        }
    });


    //This is what I have tried but i get the issue with cancelEdit
    //where when I press the TextField it cancels the editing
    cell.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, (MouseEvent e) -> {
        if (e.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)) {
            if (cell.isSelected() && e.getClickCount() >= 1) {
                languages.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                languages.getSelectionModel().select(cell.getItem());
                e.consume();
            }

            if (e.getClickCount() > 1) {

                e.consume();
            }
        }

    });

}



public String getString() {
    return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
}

@Override
public void startEdit() {
    super.startEdit();

    if (textField == null) {
        createTextField();
    }
    setText(null);
    setGraphic(textField);
    textField.selectAll();
    textField.requestFocus();
}

@Override
public void cancelEdit() {
    super.cancelEdit();
    setGraphic(null);
    setText(getItem());
    textField = null;
}

@Override
public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    cell.textProperty().unbind();
    if (empty) {
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);
    } else {
        if (isEditing()) {
            if (textField != null) {
                textField.setText(getString());
            }
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(textField);
        } else {
            setText(getString());
            setGraphic(getGraphic());
        }
    }
}

private void createTextField() {
    textField = new TextField(getString());

    textField.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
            if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                if (textField.getText().trim() != "" && textField.getText().trim().length() > 3) {
                    commitEdit(textField.getText());
                    setGraphic(null);
                    setGraphic(getGraphic());

                }

            } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                cancelEdit();
            }

        }
    });

}
}
```

This is the `LanguageCellFactory` class

```
package application;

import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import application.LanguageListCell;

public class LanguageCellFactory implements Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>> {

public LanguageCellFactory()
{

}

@Override

public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> languages)
{
    return new LanguageListCell(languages);    
}

}
```

And this is the `Main` class

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import application.LanguageCellFactory;



public class Main extends Application {
private ListView<String> languages;
private Stage stage;


@Override
public void init()
{
}

public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,800,600);

        ArrayList<String> list_items = new ArrayList<String>();
        list_items.add("Russian");
        list_items.add("English");

        languages = new ListView<String>();
        languages.relocate(150, 62);
        languages.getItems().addAll(list_items);
        root.getChildren().add(languages);

        //languages.setEditable(true);

        languages.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
        languages.setCellFactory(new LanguageCellFactory());

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("First JavaFX App");
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If someone wants to know how to fix this, I tried removing the editing events for the `ListCell` and provided my own "editing" behaviour for the cells and now it is working

Here is the modified version of the `LanguageListCell` class

```
package application;

import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

public class LanguageListCell extends ListCell<String> {
private TextField textField;
LanguageListCell cell = this;
int i = 0;

private boolean textfield_state = false;

ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
MenuItem editItem = new MenuItem();

public LanguageListCell(ListView<String> languages) {


    editItem.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("Edit \"%s\"", cell.itemProperty()));



    contextMenu.getItems().add(editItem);

    cell.textProperty().bind(cell.itemProperty());

    cell.emptyProperty().addListener((obs, wasEmpty, isNowEmpty) -> {
        if (isNowEmpty) {
            cell.setContextMenu(null);
        } else {
            if (getString() != "Add") {
                cell.setContextMenu(contextMenu);

            }
        }
    });


}



public String getString() {
    return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
}

@Override
public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    cell.textProperty().unbind();
    //String thecellValue = getString();
    if (empty) {
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);
    } else {
        if (textfield_state) {
            if (textField != null) {
                textField.setText(getString());
            }
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(textField);
        } else {
            setText(getString());
            setGraphic(getGraphic());
            editItem.setOnAction(event -> {
                textfield_state = true;
                if(textField == null) 
                {
                    createTextField();
                }
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
                textField.requestFocus();
                textField.selectAll();
            });
        }
    }
}

private void createTextField() {
    textField = new TextField(getString());

    String CellValue = getString();

    textField.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
            if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                if (textField.getText().trim() != "" && textField.getText().trim().length() > 3) {
                    setText(textField.getText().trim());
                    setGraphic(null);

                }

            } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                //cancelEdit();
                setGraphic(null);
                setText(CellValue);
                textField = null;
            }

        }
    });

    textField.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, isNotFocused, isFocused) -> {
        if(isFocused)
        {
            LanguageListCell parent = (LanguageListCell) textField.getParent();
            ListView<String> list = parent.getListView();
            list.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
            list.getSelectionModel().select(parent.getIndex());
        }
        else
        {
            setGraphic(null);
            setText(CellValue);
            textField = null;
        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: whatever you want to achieve: this is completely wrong! if you want the editing to have any permanent effect, you MUST use the proper edit mechanisms (start/commit/cancelEdit on the cell level, plus maybe a custom editCommitHandler on the ListView).

Comment: as to your requirement, I don't understand why you want to by-pass the standard ux of mouse gestures .. you'll confuse your users ..